# Postcard transcription, german, old handwriting

Tags: handwriting, kurrent

I got my hands on an old german postcard and I am trying to read it.

For now that is how far I got (but I am not sure if everything is really right):

> Liebe Freunde!
>
> Betrefs euhrem kommen kann ich euch  mitteilen daß mir
>
> dieser XXX meiner  XXX von Karl zum XXX haben  wenn es euch auf XXX so
>
> meiner  mir lieben XXX XXX auf bis in 14 Tagen  kommen müsset den
>
> jetzt kann ich  mich XXX XXX so XXX XXX XXX  XXX ja nirgens XXX zum
>
> auftreiben  könnt XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX
>
> XXX XXX XXX von mir
> XXX
>
> XXX

Can anyone read and help me with it?
Thanks!
Also, if anyone might be able to read the full address, I would also be very interested in this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erster Versuch - zur Weiterbearbeitung als community wiki.

```
                  Wallsee am 1(?)/8
Liebe Freunde!
Betrefs euhrem kommen kann ich euch
mitteilen daß wir di(e)ser Woche [Wochen ?] einen
Totenfall von Karl zum erwarten haben
wenn es euch nich(t) hindert so wäre
mir lieber wenn Ihr erst bis in 14 Tagen
kommen würdet den(n) jetz(t) kann ich
mich euch nich(t) so widmen. Woanders 
ist ja nirgen(d)s etwas zum auftreiben.
Könnt nun tun wie Ihr wol(l)t.
Seid herzlich gegrüßt von mir
XXX
XXX
```

Die Adresse:

```
An
Herrn u Frau
Meisel
im Oberndorf N. 2
Post Altheim
bei Braunau am Inn
```

Altheim (bzw. [Oberndorf](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/33774605)) liegt im Innviertel, Oberösterreich.